Mean of weekly data smoothed with a 3-week moving average
I have weekly Influenza data for 6 years and I want to find the mean to plot over time so that I can compare to the weekly data for 2024 so far (here is the dataset). The problem I have is that the organisation that tracks the flu data in the country employs a 3-week trailing moving average as the weekly data has fluctuations due to testing. As a result, I am not sure if I should:
(1) First work out the 3-week moving average for each year and then find the mean; or
(2) Find the mean, and then from the weekly mean data, smooth that with a 3-week moving average
I want to be able to compare it to the 3-week moving average data of 2024

I can't figure out what (2) does.  Could you elaborate on it or provide a simple worked example?
